# Is it possible to use ASCII code in .MoveEndUntil?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new in VBA for Word

I was wondering if it is possible to use ASCII code in `.MoveEndUntil` for example: `.MoveEndUntil cset:=Chr(13) & "-", Count:=wdForward`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Expand the range to the next list item? Or to a paragraph starting with an actual dash/hyphen character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is totally possible to use sample code from your question. However, it depends what you are trying to achieve. Your code will move the end of the selection until any of the specified characters are found in the document (see the documentation of the [`Range.MoveEndUntil`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197156%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method).

That means that moving the end of the range will stop as soon as a dash *or* a carriage return is reached.

However, this is probably not what you want. It looks like you are trying to extend the range until the next list item? If this should be the case then you can't use a simple `Range.MoveEndUntil`. You would have to expand the range to the end of the current paragraph and check whether the following paragraph has a list formatting.

Comment: What do you mean by "That means that moving the end of the range will stop as soon as a dash or a carriage return is reached". So you mean that the code will choose only either of the two and not the two of them combined?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the `MoveEndUntil` method does.

Comment: how about given this example `-Why you think there's so many(carriage return)
ducks in comics and cartoons?(carriage return)
There's Daffy Duck,(carriage return)
Daisy Duck,(carriage return)
Howard the Duck,(carriage return)
Scrooge McDuck,(carriage return)
Huey, Dewey, and Louie,(carriage return)
Baby Huey--(carriage return)
I mean, what--(carriage return)
that's a lot of ducks.(carriage return)
-You can't get away from 'em,(carriage return)
I guess.`(carriage return)` I want it to reach from `-Why you ...` to `of ducks.(carriage return)`

Comment: This can probably best be done using a find (search) using wildcard.